# Is there a way to force all browsers to be treated the same in IIS?

Tags: iis-7, asp.net-4.0, internet-explorer-11

I am dealing with an issue where a legacy website reliant on third party controls is not rendering correctly in IE 11. In IE 11, if we change the user agent to something other than 11, it renders fine. So I don't believe it is an issue within IE 11 itself but instead the dynamically generated controls from the third party are not being generated correctly.

We have a requirement to get the site working in IE 8 - 11, without compatibility mode. No other browsers must be supported (though naturally it is better if they are.) The third party's most recent version supposedly does not have this issue but they have removed the legacy controls that we use so if we upgrade we would need to spend time migrating to the new controls and any new bugs those expose.

Is there a way, perhaps using a .browser file, to have every incoming request to be treated as if they were an IE 8 UA, or IE9 or 10 in IIS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We came up with a solution that seems to be working.

We installed an add-in to IIS called 'URL ReWrite 2.0' which you can get through the Web Platform Installer available from Microsoft.

We added HTTP_USER_AGENT as a valid variable through the add-in and then added a rule to change the HTTP_USER_AGENT for every incoming request to a selected IE 8 one. Now the site returns identical css/html/javascript for every request.